# Import.io > Extractor : page never load, so cannot extract datas

Tags: import.io

Import.io is working pretty fine, but there is one website I would like to extract datas, but when I start the extractor, then enter the URL http://restaurant.michelin.fr/restaurants/france/75000-paris/restaurants-michelin/page-4/ which is loaded. Then I press the ON button, but the page won't load, nothing is displayed.... blank page and looks like it's still loading... In that case, how can I do ? I've also tried with the crawler, but same result. I restarted the program and computer but always the same issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The import.io desktop app browser uses firefox24. Few websites aren't compatible with the browser and this appears to be what is happening in this case.

It does however work in Magic! https://magic.import.io/

Once you have published the Magic API, you can then use the tools in MyData such as Bulk and Chain to add more URLs.

I have just tried to save a Magic API and it worked a treat. The only disadvantage here is that you won't be able to edit the columns until after you have extracted the data.

Comment: Hey Alex, thank you so much for your answer. Magic API is working just fine for tis kind of page with list. It helps me a lot. But if I try for a single page with specific informations to take (ex : if I want restaurant's name, adress, etc for http://restaurant.michelin.fr/restaurant/france/75007-paris-07/auguste/2dof8zp) Magic can't do the work. But again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tsootsoo I see. Yes, Magic doesn't work with single item pages just yet. We'll (import.io) shortly be releasing a new web-based product, which will mean you can do both!